# Displaying GMT in users Time Zone using DateTime and DateTimeZone not working

Tags: php, oop, datetime, timezone

**Background**

I am trying to create an events scheduler that shows a days worth of events to a user. It looks like this.

[image]

On the left you can see the 15min time intervals, and underneath each interval is the corresponding unix timestamp.

**problem:**

Take two users for example.

Gemma is from london which is +01:00 GMT

Françoise comes from Paris which is +02:00 GMT

When Gemma looks at her events schedule each 15 minute row should show ...

- a) the time in their timezone and
- b) the corresponding unix timestamp

So take the timeslots from 10:00 AM to 11:00 AM GMT at 2016-9-30 for example, they would look something like this.

> For Gemma:
>
> - 11:00 => 1475229600 (10:00 GMT)
> - 11:15 => 1475230500 (10:15 GMT)
> - 11:30 => 1475231400 (10:30 GMT)
> - 11:45 => 1475232300 (10:45 GMT)
> - 12:00 => 1475233200 (11:00 GMT)
>
> For Françoise:
>
> - 12:00 => 1475229600 (10:00 GMT)
> - 12:15 => 1475230500 (10:15 GMT)
> - 12:30 => 1475231400 (10:30 GMT)
> - 12:45 => 1475232300 (10:45 GMT)
> - 13:00 => 1475233200 (11:00 GMT)

**My Code**

Here are my functions which generate the time slots

```
/**
 * intervals
 */
public function getTimeSlots($year, $month, $day, $start_time = '06:00', $end_time = '20:00')
{
    $date = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day; // 2016-9-30
    $unix_base_time = $this->getUnixTimeStamp($date); // unix timestamp for 2016-9-30 00:00

    $seconds_start = strtotime('1970-01-01 ' . $start_time . ' UTC'); // 21600 seconds
    $seconds_end   = strtotime('1970-01-01 ' . $end_time . ' UTC');   // 72000 seconds

    while ($seconds_start <= $seconds_end) {
        $slots[$unix_base_time + $seconds_start] = $this->getTime($date, '+' . $seconds_start . ' seconds');
        $seconds_start = $seconds_start + 900; // plus 15 minutes
    }
    return $slots;
}

/**
 * timestamps
 */
public function getUnixTimeStamp($offset = 'now')
{
    $date = new DateTime($offset, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    return $date->format('U'); // returns a unix timestamp
}


/**
 * time
 */
public function getTime($date = 'now', $offset = 'now')
{
    $date = new DateTime($date, new DateTimeZone($this->session->userdata('time_zone')));
    $date->modify($offset);
    return $date->format('H:i');
}
```

If I var_dump the output I get the following:

```
array(57) {
  [1475215200]=>
  string(5) "06:00"
  [1475216100]=>
  string(5) "06:15"
  [1475217000]=>
  string(5) "06:30"
  [1475217900]=>
  string(5) "06:45"
  [1475218800]=>
  string(5) "07:00"
  etc......
}
```

The unix timestamp is correct, but the times are displaying as GMT and not the users time zone!

So obviously I am doing something wrong in the getTime() function.

I can't work out why it is returning the time ('H:i') as GMT when I am clearly injecting the DateTimeZone object with the users timezone passed as an argument.

Comment: A few additional comments that are unrelated to your answer. Look into DateTimeInterval. You can generate a start date and end date as a DateTime object and compare them with `<`. You can then add a date time interval to your start date for each iteration. That way you don't have to mix `strtotime` and `DateTime`, but do everything with `DateTime` with in my experience is less error prone.

Comment: Great advice, going to look into it now. This is proving more of a challenge then I expected.

Comment: Dealing with dates is hard. There are a lot of pitfalls (leap year, leap seconds, etc). `DateTime` isn't easy to understand, but once learned it's an incredible useful tool and saves you from a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new `DateTime` object the timezone that you pass in is considered the timezone of the passed in date. In your case you are telling `DateTime` to interpret the seconds once as GMT+1 and once as GMT+2.

Try the following instead:

```
// our $date is in UTC because we derived it from unix timestamps
$date = new DateTime($date,
       new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->modify($offset);
// update the timezone. The time will be interpreted accordingly.
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($this->session>userdata('time_zone')));
return $date->format('H:i');
```